# Getting the client request domain from Lambda@Edge function

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I'm trying do something like below for HTTP 301 redirect, so that web users will redirect to different news pages.

```html
    if ((request.uri == "/news") || (request.uri == "/news/") && (request.origin.domainName == "sub.mydomain.com")) {

        
        const redirectResponse = {
            status: '301',
            statusDescription: 'Moved Permanently',
            headers: {
                'location': [{
                    key: 'Location',
                    value: '/local-news/',
                }],
                'cache-control': [{
                    key: 'Cache-Control',
                    value: "max-age=3600"
                }],
            },
        };
        callback(null, redirectResponse);
   
  }
```

However, seems like this **request.origin.domainName == "mydomain.com"** part is not working in my function. Is this correct way to pick the domain name which client coming from?

I think this **request.origin.domainName** method will not work as **Origin** Object support only for **Origin requests**. Is there any possibility, that I can get the domain name which client coming from for the **Viewer requests**?

The reason I need this is, I've multiple domains, that users access the same CloudFront distribution. Hence, when user coming from different domains, user must be redirected to different news sites.

Can anyone support me on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get distribution Domain Name

```
  const distributionDomain = event.Records[0].cf.config.distributionDomainName;
```

The more information You can find in [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html)

Also, check

[Lambda@Edge Example Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html)

[Doc](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=798640&tstart=0)

[accessing origin URL from AWS lambda@edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47817019/accessing-origin-url-from-aws-lambdaedge)

Also, try this way

```
'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const response = event.Records[0].cf.response;
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const hostHeader = request.headers['host'][0].value;
    callback(null, response);
};
```

`hostHeader` should be the CNAME(domain name)

The more info [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/generating-dynamic-error-responses-in-amazon-cloudfront-with-lambdaedge/)

Comment: Thanks for the response @CyberEternal. `distributionDomainName` gives the CloudFront distribution domain. I actually want my custom domain (CNAME created to CloudFront address) which user access the website.

Comment: This is cool and it works like charm. Thank you so much. Would like to check with you, if you can help me to understand, can I do something like `https://test.mydomain.com/data/news*` >  `https://test.mydomain.com/data/local-news$1` 301 redirections?

Comment: I think You can check the path parameters of the viewer request or origin request, and add the logic for the condition.

Comment: If we talk about an Lambda@Edge handling origin origin requests, the `distributionDomainName` value is the distribution default domain (`whatever.cloudfront.net`), and the `request.headers['host'][0].value` value is the origin domain name. None of these is equal to the hostname that the client used to send the request to the distribution.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the real client domain (hostname) in lambda edge origin request event - you must set an Origin request policy on the behaviour your lambda is running on:

1. go to your distribution
2. go to bahaviour and click edit (where your lambda is invoked)
3. set set an Origin request policy: Managed-AllViewerAndCloudFrontHeaders-2022-06

the request look like this:
2024-01-17T21:47:20.808Z    04f76459-6b43-47f4-bc8d-401e52af458c    INFO    request:
{
"clientIp": "93.206.59",
"headers": {
"host": [
{
"key": "Host",
"value": "stag.niil.co.il"
}
],
"cloudfront-is-mobile-viewer": [
{
"key": "CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer",
"value": "false"
}
],
"cloudfront-is-tablet-viewer": [
{
"key": "CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer",
"value": "false"
}
],
"cloudfront-is-smarttv-viewer": [
{
"key": "CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer",
"value": "false"
}
],
"cloudfront-is-desktop-viewer": [
{
"key": "CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer",
"value": "true"
}
],
"cloudfront-is-ios-viewer": [
{
"key": "CloudFront-Is-IOS-Viewer",
"value": "false"
}
],
"cloudfront-is-android-viewer": [
{
"key": "CloudFront-Is-Android-Viewer",
"value": "false"
}
],
"accept-language": [
{
"key": "Accept-Language",
"value": "en-US,en;q=0.9,he-IL;q=0.8,he;q=0.7"
}
],
"accept": [
{
"key": "Accept",
"value": "image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8"
}
],
"referer": [
{
"key": "Referer",
"value": "https://stng.mi.co.il/"
}
],
"cloudfront-forwarded-proto": [
{
"key": "CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto",
"value": "https"
}
],
"x-forwarded-for": [
{
"key": "X-Forwarded-For",
"value": "93.2.59"
}
],
"user-agent": [
{
"key": "User-Agent",
"value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/57.36"
}
],
"via": [
{
"key": "Via",
"value": "2.0 1a425dcbf8d7a7da.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)"
}
],
"accept-encoding": [
{
"key": "Accept-Encoding",
"value": "br,gzip"
}
],
"sec-ch-ua": [
{
"key": "sec-ch-ua",
"value": ""Not_A Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="120", "Google Chrome";v="120""
}
],
"sec-ch-ua-mobile": [
{
"key": "sec-ch-ua-mobile",
"value": "?0"
}
],
"sec-ch-ua-platform": [
{
"key": "sec-ch-ua-platform",
"value": ""macOS""
}
],
"sec-fetch-site": [
{
"key": "sec-fetch-site",
"value": "same-origin"
}
],
"sec-fetch-mode": [
{
"key": "sec-fetch-mode",
"value": "no-cors"
}
],
"sec-fetch-dest": [
{
"key": "sec-fetch-dest",
"value": "image"
}
],
"cloudfront-viewer-http-version": [
{
"key": "CloudFront-Viewer-HTTP-Version",
"value": "2.0"
}
],
"cloudfront-viewer-country": [
{
"key": "CloudFront-Viewer-Country",
"value": "IL"
}
],
"cloudfront-viewer-country-name": [
{
"key": "CloudFront-Viewer-Country-Name",
"value": "Israel"
}
],
"cloudfront-viewer-country-region": [
{
"key": "CloudFront-Viewer-Country-Region",
"value": "TA"
}
],
"cloudfront-viewer-country-region-name": [
{
"key": "CloudFront-Viewer-Country-Region-Name",
"value": "Tel Aviv"
}
],
"cloudfront-viewer-city": [
{
"key": "CloudFront-Viewer-City",
"value": "Ramat Gan"
}
],
"cloudfront-viewer-time-zone": [
{
"key": "CloudFront-Viewer-Time-Zone",
"value": "Asia/Jerusalem"
}
],
"cloudfront-viewer-latitude": [
{
"key": "CloudFront-Viewer-Latitude",
"value": "32.08210"
}
],
"cloudfront-viewer-longitude": [
{
"key": "CloudFront-Viewer-Longitude",
"value": "34.81220"
}
],
"cloudfront-viewer-address": [
{
"key": "CloudFront-Viewer-Address",
"value": "93.172.206.59:55502"
}
],
"cloudfront-viewer-tls": [
{
"key": "CloudFront-Viewer-TLS",
"value": "TLSv1.3:TLS_AES_GCM_SHA256:connectionReused"
}
],
"cloudfront-viewer-asn": [
{
"key": "CloudFront-Viewer-ASN",
"value": "1680"
}
]
},
"method": "GET",
"origin": {
"custom": {
"customHeaders": {},
"domainName": "943351998-staging.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
"keepaliveTimeout": 5,
"path": "",
"port": 80,
"protocol": "http",
"readTimeout": 30,
"sslProtocols": [
"TLSv1.2"
]
}
},
"querystring": "",
"uri": "/favicon/favicon-16x16.png"
}